# Can I use a Google static map as a background?

Tags: css, google-maps-static-api

I'm trying to apply a Google static map as a background for a div element. Is this possible? I'm using the image-background CSS property at the moment.

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer when you get one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply save the image by navigating to the URL of your static map and use it as a background like any other image.

```
.map-div {
    background-image:url('static-map.png');
}
```

The maximum resolution it can be is [640x640](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=fr#Imagesizes), which may or may not be sufficient, however you can use a [scale value](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/?hl=fr#scale_values) of 2 to get a 1280x1280 image.

Comment: Thanks, 640x640 isn't sufficent for what I need, but maybe someone else could use this.

Comment: Added a note about scaling if that can help you.

Comment: I wonder if saving a static maps image is not a violation of Google's terms and conditions, e.g. [10.1.1.(g) No Use of Content without a Google Map.](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1)...

Answer (score -1):

Yes, this is very possible.

You'll need a Google API key and some knowledge of CSS3.

Read more about how to do it and get some sample code here: http://blog.wadehammes.com/post/3837158298

Use this code to disable all controls:

```
function initialize() {
var mapOptions = {
zoom: 4,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
disableDefaultUI: true,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
   mapOptions);
```

}

Comment: That's not a static map, unfortunately.